Why is my QuestDB query so slow and not using symbol column for filter?
I have a dataset of about 1 billion rows from the last 6 months, partitioned by day. Data is spiky - sometimes partition might have 100M rows, sometimes 20-30k only. The table is like this
SHOW COLUMNS FROM state;


And I run the following query
SELECT tag_id, avg(value) as value, timestamp
FROM state
WHERE
  tag_id = '/Objects/Sensors/MotionReferenceUnit/Roll' AND
  id = 'LAB11111' AND
  eid = 'Crane1' AND
  timestamp between '2024-05-03T00:00:00.00' and '2024-07-01T00:00:00.00'
SAMPLE BY 1h;

It takes almost 30 seconds to complete! Explain gives me this:
Sort light
  keys: [timestamp]
    GroupBy vectorized: false
      keys: [tag_id, timestamp]
      values: [avg(value)]
        DataFrame
            Index forward scan on: eid
              filter: eid=19 and (id='LAB11111' and eid='Crane1')
            Interval forward scan on: state
              intervals: [("2024-05-03T00:00:00.000000Z","2024-07-01T00:00:00.000000Z")]

So for some reason tag_id is not being used to filter the data, despite being the main filter (its an indexed symbol field). Thats strange, I don't really understand why. The total number of datapoints matching this query (without the sample) is about 30 million.
Total number of unique tag_id values in the table is 184.
I can do queries like this on demo.questdb.io with a much larger dataset and have results within milliseconds. How come it takes so long for my own dataset? My QuestDB running locally is taking anywhere from 4GB to 8GB of RAM. Total volume of data on disk is about 20GB. Sub-second precision.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Do you get rows with tag_id different from the '/Objects/Sensors/MotionReferenceUnit/Roll' value in the result set? If so, this could be a bug.

As for the query execution time, your query ends up using the eid column index and the index-based scan is single-threaded. If the index is not selective (i.e. there are not many distinct eid values), this could be the limiting factor. Try dropping the index to force parallel SQL execution.

Thanks for the insights @AndreiPechkurov . Indeed, removing all filters except the tag_id does indeed make the DB use the filter correctly.
However, after completely removing the database and all data, re-creating and then re-importing the whole dataset also fixed the query and made it complete just 6 seconds (still too long IMO). It should be noted that after re-creating there is no index anymore on the tag_id column as its added and re-indexed later. So this really does look like a bug. Should I open a bug report?

PS: No, there is no results that have different tag_id than the /Objects/Sensors/MotionReferenceUnit/Roll

Ok and confirm - as soon as I add index with ALTER TABLE state ALTER COLUMN tag_id ADD INDEX; and the database reindexes the column, the old behavior and slow queries come back. I will open a bug report.

"Should I open a bug report?" - Yes, please! Thanks for doing trying this out.
